# xcode loading view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to show a progress view while my app is downloading files when starts. Loading view should be active until download ends, then, main tab controller will be shown. Which is the best method to reach it? Thanks

Comment: push a view when starting and dismiss when download ends, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, loading the "main tab controller" first and then adding a view on top which shows the Progress should do the work.

Maybe MBProgressHUD ([GitHub](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD)) could be interesting for you.

It's nice if the user will see little more then only progress. So make the View in Front translucent.